# Kill a hung process

Tags: windows-8.1, process

**Edit**: People are downvoting. Can you guys explain why?

So, I'm working on something with batch files, but, sometimes, when I try to close them in the middle of their code, they'll hang.

The issue is, I can't close these hanged windows.

These are the things I've tried:

- Task Manager > End Process (**Just doesn't work**)
- Process Hacker > Terminate (**Error: An attempt was made to access an exiting process**)
- Process Hacker > Terminator; all of the options besides TT4 (**None of them work**)
- `taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"`

I'm on Windows 8.1

**The only way I have been able to close these processes is by logging off and back on.** This means there *must* be a way to close them, no? So can I do that without logging off?

Comment: Use Kernel Detective provided by AT4RE

Comment: "Unsupported operating system"

Comment: It seems like the problem might be related to the kinds of things the batch file is doing at the time.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: A few times, they were in a very quickly looping loop -- no delay. I have that no more, so that's no issue. The one other time was when it was compiling via `java -jar ___.jar` in Git. It hung since I tried to exit when it was loading resources, I think.

Comment: @PieCrust try compatibility -> run as windows XP

Comment: Don't know who is downvoting but this is a valid question. I have the same issue with Windows 10. Additional information: `taskkill` "`Reason: There is no running instance of the task."`

Comment: Maybe it's an unkillable process. Please see ["How can I kill an unkillable process?"](https://superuser.com/questions/136272/how-can-i-kill-an-unkillable-process) and [my comment on that question](https://superuser.com/questions/136272/how-can-i-kill-an-unkillable-process#comment1727588_136272).

Comment: The error message you saw, "An attempt was made to access an exiting process", is the MessageText for the MessageId `STATUS_PROCESS_IS_TERMINATING`, which is NTSTATUS 0xC000010A. All this is according to the "ntstatus.h" header file, which is included in the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can try opening Command Prompt as administrator, typing...

> Taskkill /im cmd.exe /f

and pressing Enter. This will kill all batch files and Command Prompt windows.

Or find the PID of the batch file by opening Task Manager, going to the Processes tab, right clicking the name of the unresponsive window, and clicking "Go to details". Note the PID of the selected process, then open Command Prompt as admin and type...

> Taskkill /pid (insert PID) /f

and press Enter. This will kill that batch file specifically but not other windows.

Comment: I've tried taskkill, unfortunately that does not work. Let me add that to my list.

Comment: Oh. Sorry for wasting your time then.

Comment: No problem, it was my fault as I had forgotten to add it to the list of things I did try :]