# Cannot stop Avira Antivirus service: access denied

Tags: windows-7, windows, anti-virus, avira

I want to stop Avira Anti Virus services in `services.msc`. *Stop service* is disabled for me. I am administrator of the computer. I installed it from the same account from which I am trying to stop.

If I try to kill the process from Task Manager, it says *Access Denied*. What's up with this antivirus?

I need to stop it as it is causing problems in my software development.

Comment: You can disble the protection against this in Avira's security settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to uninstall it, or disable it from the control panel / options that come with the A/V. Many viruses try to do the same thing you're doing (disabling the service) so that they can turn off the antivirus, so many A/V products mark their services as critical so that that can't happen.

Comment: If you have trouble uninstalling the antivirus, you could try using [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can kill a process which doesn't let you by using [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/downloads.php). Process Hacker is a free, powerful, multi-purpose tool that helps you monitor system resources, debug software and detect malware.

**Main features**

- A detailed overview of system activity with highlighting
- Graphs and statistics allow you quickly to track down resource hogs and runaway processes.
- Can't edit or delete a file? Discover which processes are using that file.
- See what programs have active network connections, and close them if necessary.
- Get real-time information on disk access.

**Advanced features**

- View detailed stack traces with kernel-mode, WOW64 and .NET support.
- Go beyond services.msc: create, edit and control services.

Source: [Kill a process which says "Access denied"](https://superuser.com/questions/109010/kill-a-process-which-says-access-denied)

Comment: Please exercise caution when recommending software. As written, your answer may be seen as spam. Your answer should include a description of the software and how it addresses the question. More information: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)

Comment: Note to reviewers: While the answer should contain a brief description of the software, Process Hacker is *not* spam (http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5996/community-promotion-ads-2013/6056#6056).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Could not install it. It kept coming back.
Then I did the following according to the instructions at:
https://answers.avira.com/en/question/how-do-i-perform-a-manual-uninstallation-of-avira-antivirus-9190

I downloaded a utility from their site: 
http://install.avira-update.com/package/regcleaner/win32/en/avira_registry_cleaner_en.exe

Booted into windows restricted mode (press the shift key and restart at the same time and go thru the dialog).

Then ran Avira uninstall via Revo Uninstaller Pro and also removed all the other files (part of the Revo Pro dialog).

Then ran the Avira registry cleaner.

Then rebooted the pc - no more Avira!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to safe mode and copy it to another place and back to windows it will stop. But every time you want update avira must reverse this work.

And you install Process Lasso and terminate it forever.

Answer (score 0):

100% SOLUTION in 7': Remove hdd or ssd. - plug it as external or 2nd internal to another PC - Search entire disk for "avira"  - Select&Delete ALL search results->DONE

After trying literally every other solution for hours with zero results, i did this in less than 7 minutes. Even if u don't have a second pc, it is better to go with your hdd or ssd to a friend a do the above than spending hours installing removal tools, revo and iobit uninstallers, going into safe modes, wathing tutorials, searching forums etc with no results.