# Process Outlook.exe can't be killed (win7/Outlook 2010)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

Occasionally my Outlook crashes and when I open task manager it shows 2 outlook.exe processes. I am able to kill the first one but the second refuses to die regardless of what I do. I tried "end process" & "end process tree" many times with no luck.

As primarily a Linux user it frustrates me that I can't just open a terminal and kill this process instead having no choice but to interrupt my work and restart the machine.

Is there anything else I can try to kill this process and not have to restart my pc?

Comment: Perhaps something like `taskkill /im outlook.exe /f` *might* help.

Comment: Have you tried opening/running Task Manager as an administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be dangerous to simply kill `Outlook.exe`. The consequence can be a corrupted `.pst` or `.ost` file.

In many cases, task manager replacement [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) or similar tools can be used to open the list of active threads within the `Outlook.exe` process. This gives an indication what could be blocking. And it allows to kill just the offending thread.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to reboot the computer, as the outlook.exe can't be killed by [any means I tried](https://superuser.com/questions/109010/kill-a-process-which-says-access-denied) once it's crashed.

If you don't want to reboot as it's inconvenitent, and you use office 365 then you can get your email in the meantime via https://outlook.office365.com/mail/