# How do you suspend a process in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, process

There is a process (Conexant Flow) that causes high CPU usage on my system. It seems to be an issue with an interaction with Firefox. I can `kill` the process, but it restarts seconds later and starts hammering the CPU again.

I have noticed that some processes in the Task Manager show as suspended, and I think this may put paid to this rogue process, however I can't work out how to put it in this state. Is there any way to suspend a process either with a PowerShell command or another method that doesn't require administrator privileges?

Comment: Use [ProcessExplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) - it allows to suspenв particular process.

Comment: Solution to your issue in the answers here, best one is by Andrew72.....https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/Flow-exe-spikes-to-20-CPU-and-causes-sporadic-windows-freeze/td-p/6483020/page/2

Comment: Another similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/109010/kill-a-process-which-says-access-denied)